# Function with a Cooldown

Tags: python, async-await

Hello i have a Person Detector script i want to send an info if any person detected by mail.In order to prevent mail spamming i need a timer for sendMail function.Function might be triggered anytime but it will only respond if its not on cooldown.

I tried using async task but couldn't implemented because if a person detected it goes to a loop where it sends email every 5 minutes even if there isn’t any person detected after the first sight.

**Example:**

1. Person detection script is running.
2. Person detected on camera -> Send an email(start the 5 minute cooldown)
3. Person sighted again after 2 minutes(didn't send any email because there is still 3 minutes cooldown).
4. Person sighted after 6 minutes send another email(because 5 minute cooldown is over).

Summary of my code.(Necessary parts only detection and sending mail works cooldown (timer) doesn't work

```py
async def sendAlert():
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
        print('sent!')
        await asyncio.sleep(300)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            if classes[i] == 1 and scores[i] > threshold:
                with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
                    sendAlert(server)     
                box = boxes[i]
                cv2.rectangle(img,(box[1],box[0]),(box[3],box[2]),(255,0,0),2)
```

If there is a person detected, script will send an alert by email.Afterwards if a person detected again in 5 minutes sendAlert function shouldn't respond until 5 minutes passed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"couldn't implemented" [sic] is not a problem specification.  What *does* it do?  Please supply the driver program to show that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Prune that you need to create a small (minimal) use-case and present your code so that it is not only relevant to you, but also relevant to others. Additionally, your question should have a section with a verifiable example. Without these attributes, your question becomes hard for people to grasp, solve and/or suggest any verifiable solution.

However, as I understand, you have some action (sending email if a person is detected) that you would like to perform after certain `cool-off` period. So, in other words, you want a mechanism of keeping track of time. Hence, you would need the `datetime` library.

So, your pseudo code should look something like this:

### Pseudo Code

```py
import datetime

start = capture_timestamp()
cutoff = '00:05:00'
dt_cutoff = read_in_cutoff_as_timedelta(cutoff)
if person_detected:
    now = capture_timestamp()
    dt = now - start
    if dt >= dt_cutoff:
        # Send notification
        send_email_notification()
    else:
        # Do not Send Notification
        print('now: {} | dt: {}'.format(now, dt))
```

You could use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` for timestamp. And `datetime.timedelta()` for defining `dt_cutoff`. For reading in a time-string as time you could do this:

```py
tm = datetime.datetime.strptime(cutoff).time()
dt_cutoff = datetime.timedelta(hours = tm.hour, minutes = tm.minute, seconds = tm.second)
```

I hope this gives you some idea about how to model this.

## Additional Resources

1. https://www.guru99.com/date-time-and-datetime-classes-in-python.html
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
3. https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-convert-a-timestamp-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-datetime-strptime/

## Complete Solution

Now, finally if you are in a hurry to use a ready made solution, you may use the following class object as shown. All you would need is to instantiate the class object by specifying your cool-off-period (`timer_cutoff`) and then call the method `is_timeout()`. If this returns `True`, then you send your notification. There is also an `obj.istimeout` attribute which stores this decision (`True`/`False`).

```py
import time

# Set cutoff time to 2 seconds to test the output 
# after 5 seconds: expect istimeout = True
# and instantiate the TimeTracker class object.
ttk = TimeTracker(timer_cutoff = '00:00:02') # 'HH:MM:SS'
# Wait for 3 seconds
time.sleep(3)
print('start timestamp: {}'.format(ttk.timestamp_start_str))
print('cutoff timestamp'.format(ttk.timestamp_cutoff_str))
print('timer_cutoff: {}'.format(ttk.timer_cutoff_str))
# Now check if cutoff time reached
ttk.is_timeout()
print('Send Notification: {}'.format(ttk.istimeout))
print('now_timestamp: {}'.format(ttk.timestamp_now_str))
```

### class TimeTracker

Here is the class `TimeTracker` class:

```py
import datetime

class TimeTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, 
                 timer_cutoff = '00:05:00', 
                 cutoff_strformat = '%H:%M:%S'):
        self.timer_cutoff_str = timer_cutoff
        self.cutoff_strformat = cutoff_strformat
        self.timestamp_start, self.timestamp_start_str = self.get_timestamp()
        self.dt_cutoff = None # timedelta for cutoff
        self.timestamp_cutoff = None
        self.timestamp_cutoff_str = None
        self.update_timestamp_cutoff()
        self.timestamp_now = None
        self.timestamp_now_str = None
        self.dt_elapsed = None
        self.istimeout = False

    def get_timestamp(self):
        ts = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        tss = str(ts)
        return (ts, tss)

    def readin_cutoff_as_timedelta(self):
        td = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.timer_cutoff_str, 
                                        self.cutoff_strformat)
        tdm = td.time()
        self.dt_cutoff = datetime.timedelta(hours = tdm.hour, 
                                            minutes = tdm.minute, 
                                            seconds = tdm.second)


    def update_timestamp_cutoff(self):
        self.readin_cutoff_as_timedelta()
        self.timestamp_cutoff = self.timestamp_start + self.dt_cutoff
        self.timestamp_cutoff_str = str(self.timestamp_cutoff)

    def time_elapsed(self):
        self.dt_elapsed = self.timestamp_now - self.timestamp_start

    def is_timeout(self):
        self.timestamp_now, self.timestamp_now_str = self.get_timestamp()
        self.time_elapsed()
        if (self.dt_elapsed < self.dt_cutoff):
            self.istimeout = False
        else:
            self.istimeout = True

        return self.istimeout
```

Comment: You are right.I didn’t notice that at the time i was in hurry but @Prune could explain it better like you did.Thank you.